# Print beauty dataframe in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to beautify my print output for a dataframe.

```
 d = {'Carid ': [1, 2, 3], 'Carname': ['Mercedes-Benz', 'Audi', 'BMW'], 'model': ['S-Klasse AMG 63s', 'S6', 'X6 M-Power']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.head())
df.head()
```

[image]

As you can see the `print`-outpot not beauty. The last statement of `df.head()` is beauty.
Is there any option to get the same result in the `print`-statement in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display instead of print.

```
display(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. You'll want to use Jupyter's built-in display, which you'll need to import first:

```
from IPython.display import display
```

Then, instead of `print`, use `display`:

```
display(df.head())
```

Source: https://tdhopper.com/blog/printing-pandas-data-frames-as-html-in-jupyter-notebooks